# Database design - Friend activities

Tags: database, social-networking

Currently I am designing a small twitter/facebook kind of system, where in a user should be able to see his friends latest activities.

I am using ASP.NET with MySQL database.

My Friendships table is as follows:

> |Friendshipid|friend1|Friend2|confirmed|

Friend1 and Friend2 in the above table are userids.

User activities table design following:

> |activityId|userid|activity|Dated|

Now, I am looking for best way to query the latest 50 friend activities for a user.

For example, let's say if Tom logs into the system, he should be able to see latest 50 activities among all his friends.

Any pointers on the best practices, a query or any information is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have database performance concern, you may redefine the friendship table as following:

```
friendshipid, userid, friendid, confirmed
```

When you query the **latest 50 activities**, the SQL would be:

```
SELECT act.*
FROM Activities AS act
    INNER JOIN
    Friendships AS fs
    ON fs.friendid = act.userid
        AND fs.user_id = 'logon_user_id'
        AND confirmed = TRUE
ORDER BY act.dated DESC
LIMIT 50;
```

And if there is a index on Friendships(userid) column, it would give the database the chance to optimize the query.

The friendship table redefined needs to create two tuples when a friendship occur, but it still obey the rule of business, and, has performance benefit when you need it.

Comment: Finally I got this to work for me: SELECT distinct act.activityId,act.activity,act.dated
FROM Activities AS act
    INNER JOIN
    Friendship AS fs WHERE (fs.friend1 =act.userid or fs.friend2=act.userid) AND (fs.friend1=1 OR fs.friend2=1) AND act.userid!=1 AND fs.confirmed = TRUE
ORDER BY act.dated DESC
LIMIT 50;

Answer (score 2):

It largely depends on what data is stored in the Friendships table. For example, what order are the Friend1 and Friend2 fields stored in? If, for the fields (friend1, friend2) the tuple (1, 2) exists, will (2, 1) exist also?

If this is not the case, then this should work:

```
SELECT activities.* 
FROM Activities 
    INNER JOIN Friendships ON userid = friend1 OR userid = friend2 
WHERE activity.userid != [my own id]
    AND confirmed = TRUE
LIMIT 50;
```